# 1 Cor 15:20 - Is the Resurrected Jesus Singular or Plural? Is He the Firstfruit or the Firstfruits

Tags: 1-corinthians, translation-philosophy, paul

> But in fact Christ has been raised from the dead, the firstfruits[ἀπαρχή] of those who have fallen asleep.
> -1 Corinthians 15:20

The ἀπαρχή here is in the singular form and seems to clearly be in reference to the singular Christ, however, in almost every translation, it is rendered as a plural compound noun firstfruits as opposed to a singular firstfruit.

This seems odd to me. ***Why would the translators almost uniformly present Christ conceptually as a plural?***

It seems more natural to me to view Christ as the firstfruit instead of the firstfruits since he is one person, and so it seems useful to rendor ἀπαρχή as singular at least in my head.

***Should ἀπαρχή instead be singular in English translations to match the Greek singular form and Christ, the singular referent?***

Comment: Jesus is not just Lord of lords and King of kings. He is also the First fruit of the first fruits. :)

Comment: _1. ***Chiefly in plural***. The first agricultural products of a season, esp. with reference to the custom of making offerings of these to God or the gods._ [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70617?rskey=mIAPFb&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 5):

The word "firstfruit" in singular form only appears twice in the KJV translation (see Deuteronomy 18:4; Romans 11:16), all other occurrences being of the plural form.  This is despite multiple other occurrences being singular in the original language (e.g. Leviticus 2:12, Deuteronomy 18:4, etc.).  To my mind this indicates that it was an awkward singular in English, akin to attempting to express "physics" or "entrails" in a singular sense.  Indeed, the dictionary agrees that the word, in English, should always be plural.

My Dictionary.app, which has no singular entry for this word, has this definition:

> **first fruits** | ˈˌfərs(t) ˈfro͞ots | plural noun the first agricultural
> produce of a season, especially when given as an offering to God. •
> the initial results of an enterprise or endeavor: the first fruits of
> the companies' collaboration. • historical a payment to a superior by
> the new holder of an office.

When we consider the word "produce" used in this definition--is that singular or plural?  Most would agree that it is plural.  The dictionary concurs:

> noun | ˈpräd(y)o͞os, ˈprōd(y)o͞os | **things** that have been produced or
> grown, especially by farming: dairy produce.

Just as we do not typically refer to "a scissor," the word "firstfruit" is actually not typically used in English.  Using it in singular form in the KJV is as problematic, technically, as saying "cherubims" ("cherubim" is already the plural form and the "-s" is extraneous; "cherub" is the singular)--which the KJV also does.  So the fact that the KJV attests a singular spelling "firstfruit" is not good evidence that this is actually correct English.

Noah Webster, in his 1828 dictionary, appears to acknowledge the existence of the singular form, but all the examples given are for the plural, which is uncharacteristically included in the word heading (for example, Webster does not have "fruits" as part of the heading for the "fruit" entry).  See [HERE](https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/First-fruit) to view that online, also quoted below to protect against future dead links.

> **FIRST-FRUIT,
> FIRST-FRUITS,** noun
>
> 1. The fruit or produce first matured and collected in any season. Of these the Jews made an oblation to God, as an acknowledgment of his
>    sovereign dominion.
> 2. The first profits of any thing. In the church of England, the profits of every spiritual benefice for the first year.
> 3. The first or earliest effect of any thing, in a good or bad sense; as the first-fruits of grace in the heart, or the first-fruits of
>    vice.

As language evolves, and for the sake of clarity as to the intent of the original language, I personally would see no problem in replacing "firstfruits" with "firstfruit," despite the present consensus that this is not an English word.  Words are for communication, and it is highly unlikely anyone would misunderstand this.  However, it is not difficult to see why it was translated as "firstfruits," because this is grammatically the only correct option in present-day English.

Answer (score 2):

The noun in 1 Cor 15:20, ἀπαρχὴ (aparche) is nominative feminine SINGULAR.  This noun occurs a total of eight times in the NT Greek, always in the nominative feminine singular form:

- Rom 8:23 - Not only that, but we ourselves, who have the **firstfruit** of the Spirit, groan inwardly as we wait eagerly for our adoption as sons, the redemption of our bodies.
- Rom 11:16 - If the **first part** of the dough is holy, so is the whole batch; if the root is holy, so are the branches.
- Rom 16:5 - Greet also the church that meets at their house. Greet my beloved Epenetus, who was the **first convert** to Christ in the province of Asia.
- 1 Cor 15:20 - But now Christ has been raised out from the dead, the **firstfruit** of those having fallen asleep.
- 1 Cor 15:23 - But each in his own turn: Christ the **firstfruit**; then at His coming, those who belong to Him.
- 1 Cor 16:15 - Now I exhort you, brothers--you know the house of Stephanas, that it is the **firstfruit** of Achaia, and they have devoted themselves to service to the saints--
- James 1;18 - Having willed it, He brought us forth by the word of truth, for us to be a kind of **firstfruit** of His creatures.
- Rev 14:4 - These are they who have not been defiled with women; for they are pure, these following the Lamb wherever He shall go. These have been redeemed out from men as **firstfruit** to God and to the Lamb.

Now, whether one translates these as "first fruit" or firstfruits" is somewhat immaterial - even in the singular, it often means the plural as shown by the examples above.

Comment: I noticed all your translations had firstfruit in the singular is that from a published translation? If so which one?

Comment: @Austin - that is my translation to emphasize that each one was grammatically singular.  However, some are functionally plural.  For example, James 1:18  Rev 14:4 are functionally plural but grammatically singular.

Comment: Cool. thanks for clarifying.